# When to carve a goose - hot or cold

Tags: knife-skills, goose

I have roasted a goose ready for tomorrow. Would the flavour and/or texture be better if I carved it tonight when it is warm, or wait until tomorrow when it is cold from the fridge.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Since you are going to serve it as left overs either way, for *flavor* whether you carve it hot or cold does not matter very much at all.

On the other hand, when the meat is cold it sets much firmer, so it is actually much easier to carve when it is still warm.